# What does "Auth to Services" option mean in IRC?

Tags: irc

The https://webchat.freenode.net/ IRC client
has an "auth to services" option. A quick google search does not reveal what this means.

What does this option do, and when should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Auth to Services" option lets you log in when you have registered with [Freenode's NickServ](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration), which reserves your nickname and provides other privileges.

[This SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/727142/113679) has a guide for signing up with NickServ with webchat if you haven't done so before.